# Is there a better way to convert a character literal array into a character object array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to convert a character literal array into a character object array.
Right now I am just using a for loop like:

```java
char[] charLiterals = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
Character[] charObjects = new Character[charLiterals.length];

for (int character = 0; character < charLiterals.length; character++) {
    charObjects[character] = Character.valueOf(charLiterals[character]);
}
```

But is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: Define better.  Less code?  More efficient?  More readable?   Also ... what version of Java are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one liner would do.

```
Character[] charObjects = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).toArray(Character[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitive-array-to-object-array) there are multiple ways to do that. But I believe that all of them under the hood boil down to an iteration similar to the one you provided.

If you don't mind using external libraries, then `org.apache.commons.commons-lang3:3.12.0` might be the shortest and cleanest approach:

```java
int[] input = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Integer[] expected = new Integer[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

Integer[] output = ArrayUtils.toObject(input);

assertArrayEquals(expected, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving the part of converting String into Char array and directly assigning string's char value to Character array.

```
String str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";      
Character[] charObjects = new Character[str.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    charObjects[i] = Character.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
}
```